# How to send money with paypal adaptive payments when caller and sender are the same?

Tags: paypal, payment

I want to send money to affiliates on my site using PayPal's adaptive payments API.

According to [this guide](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/adaptive-payments-api) the API caller and sender are assumed to be different, so once a call is made to the adaptive payments API, the caller must redirect the seller to authorize the transaction.

In my case the caller and sender are the same; how do I just send money out of my paypal account to an email with an API call, either with adaptive payments or some other simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

We call this scenario as "implicit payment" when the API Caller and Sender are the same. Just make sure you use the same account for API Credentials (sent as HTTP headers) and also set as receiver in the Pay API call. In such cases, since the sender and API Caller are the same, no further authorizations are required on paypal.com. So you will receive Payment status as "completed" as opposed to "Created".